# AWS Glue PySpark Notebook Error (The security token included in the request is expired)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I got the below error while running the spark job for transforming 246GB of JSON file(Read from S3) to Parquet file(write to S3)

Do please help me out on how to resolve this

[image]